Monte Carlo simulation with Importance Sampling - variance of estimator vs weighted variance
I am using Monte Carlo simulations associated with Importance Sampling and I have some difficulties interpretating the variance estimator:

Using a dummy example extracted from here, I use Monte Carlo simulations to estimate the mean and standard deviation of the distribution Gamma(8) with R:
# Number of simulations
set.seed(123)
B <- 1000

# Naive Monte Carlo
x <- rgamma(B,8)
mu_hat <- cumsum(x)/(1:B)
mu_hat[B] # Theorical value: 8
sigma_hat <- sd(x)
sigma_hat # Theorical value: sqrt(8)=2.8284

# Importance Sampling Monte Carlo
x <- rnorm(B,10,3)
w_star <- dgamma(x,8)/dnorm(x,10,3)
mu_hat_IS <- cumsum(x*w_star)/(1:B)
mu_hat_IS[B]
sigma_hat_IS <- sqrt(var(x*w_star)) # Std deviation estimator of Importance Sampling Monte Carlo
sigma_hat_IS
sigma_hat_wght <- sqrt(modi::weighted.var(x,w_star)) # Weighted standard deviation calculated using the Importance Sampling weights
sigma_hat_wght


What is the interpretation of sigma_hat_IS? I understand that, when Importance Sampling is used wisely, sigma_hat_IS < sigma_hat, so the confidence interval around mu_hat_IS is more narrow than the confidence interval around mu_hat. Is there a theorical link between sigma_hat_IS and the standard deviation of the initial distribution Gamma(8) which is equal to 2.8284?
If I want to calculate the standard deviation of the initial distribution Gamma(8) (which is equal to 2.8284) from the simulations with Importance Sampling, does it make sense to use the weighted variance formula associated to the weights of the Importance Sampling algorithm weighted.var(x,w_star)?


You should not confuse the variance of the Monte Carlo estimator of the mean of the distribution of interest  with the Monte Carlo estimator of the variance of the distribution of interest.
